# Heroku add certificate for app on EU region doesn't works for *.herokuapp.com

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, ssl-certificate

Following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint
I've added a certificate for my domain `www.example.com` and then `https://www.example.com` is working as expected.

But the domain of my certificate is `example.com` and it's not valid for `my-app.herokuapp.com` so the browser shows an error message of invalid domain for certificate.

I've seen https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/heroku-error-ssl/ but it's not valid on EU region. In fact I don't understand how it works, because the custom SSL endpoint they provide to us still has an other domain: `herokussl.com` so my certificate will not be valid for this domain.

Any ideas?